# How to divide numbers and integers?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I'm trying to divide 2 integers but the results returns zero no matter what. Should I use float or what? I just can't get it to work. I've tried floats but I get weird results. Here's my code:

```
    NSUInteger someNumber = 156;
    NSUInteger points = 597;
    NSUInteger otherNumber = 5;
    NSUInteger difference = (someNumber - points);
    NSLog(@"%d", difference);
    NSUInteger divide = (difference / otherNumber);
    NSLog(@"%d", divide);
    NSUInteger multiply = (divide * 4826);
    NSLog(@"%d", multiply);
    NSUInteger total = (358 - multiply);
    NSLog(@"%d", total);
```

Any help would be much appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: The U in "NSUInteger" is for "unsigned," so the value of `difference` above is not going to be what you probably expect. Likewise, the "Integer" in "NSUInteger" means that you're dealing in whole numbers, so `divide` isn't going to be what you probably expect either. Use a type that supports real numbers, like float or double instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally fixed it!!! I had to change difference to a float.

```
NSUInteger difference = (someNumber - points);
```

to

```
float difference = (someNumber - points);
```

Comment: This won't work in a situation such as `NSNumber *someNumber = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: (4 / 3)];` You'll get an integer result, unless you cast at least one of the numbers as (float) or (double), as Catcall says.

Answer (score 10):

Integer division truncates. To divide the two integers *i* and *j* and get a decimal fraction, you might use one of these for simple expressions. Code more complex expressions with all the caution that floating-point arithmetic requires. (Among other things, guarding against division by zero, loss of precision, and overflow.)

```
r = (float) i / j;
r = (double) i / j;
```

Answer (score 1):

NSUIntegers have a minimum value of 0. If you're expecting negative values, you should be using NSInteger.

Comment: I'm not expecting negative values, I can't get any value...XD

Comment: 156 - 597 (someNumber - xp) yields a negative value.

Comment: Oops, I just typed in random numbers for demonstration. That's my fault, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Shot in the dark, try the string formatter `%u` instead.